# Parse LLDP output with Python

Tags: python, networking

`lldpctl -f keyvalue` gives me output in this format:

```
lldp.eth0.via=LLDP
lldp.eth0.rid=1
lldp.eth0.age=286 days, 06:58:09
lldp.eth0.chassis.mac=<removed>
lldp.eth0.chassis.name=<removed>
lldp.eth0.chassis.descr=Not received
lldp.eth0.port.ifname=Gi1/19
lldp.eth0.port.descr=GigabitEthernet1/19
lldp.eth0.port.auto-negotiation.supported=yes
lldp.eth0.port.auto-negotiation.enabled=yes
lldp.eth0.port.auto-negotiation.10Base-T.hd=yes
lldp.eth0.port.auto-negotiation.10Base-T.fd=yes
lldp.eth0.port.auto-negotiation.100Base-X.hd=no
lldp.eth0.port.auto-negotiation.100Base-X.fd=yes
lldp.eth0.port.auto-negotiation.1000Base-T.hd=yes
lldp.eth0.port.auto-negotiation.1000Base-T.fd=yes
lldp.eth0.port.auto-negotiation.current=1000BaseTFD - Four-pair Category 5 UTP, full duplex mode
lldp.eth0.vlan.vlan-id=<removed>
lldp.eth0.vlan.pvid=yes
lldp.eth1.via=LLDP
lldp.eth1.rid=2
lldp.eth1.age=286 days, 06:58:08
lldp.eth1.chassis.mac=<removed>
lldp.eth1.chassis.name=<removed>
lldp.eth1.chassis.descr=Not received
lldp.eth1.port.ifname=Gi1/19
lldp.eth1.port.descr=GigabitEthernet1/19
lldp.eth1.
```

I want to use Python to parse the output into a dictionary like this:

```
lldp['eth1']['port']['descr'] = 'GigabitEthernet1/19'
```

With this consideration too:

```
lldp['eth0']['rid'] = '1'
```

Is there a reliable way to do this with python where I have an unpredictable depth to parse through?

Comment: Something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20386727/how-to-parse-and-print-a-tree-in-python/20388111#20388111

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have the output in a multiline string named `output`:

```
output_dict = {}
lldp_entries = output.split("\n")

for entry in lldp_entries:
    path, value = entry.strip().split("=", 1)
    path = path.split(".")
    path_components, final = path[:-1], path[-1]

    current_dict = output_dict
    for path_component in path_components:
        current_dict[path_component] = current_dict.get(path_component, {})
        current_dict = current_dict[path_component]
    current_dict[final] = value
```